# Change description of an OU via System.DirectoryServices C#

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I need to change several time the description of an OU> We can't use PowerShell. How do I check and change an OU description via  System.DirectoryServices; and C#

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of DirectoryEntry with the distinguished name of the object (prefixed with `LDAP://`). For example:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=YourOU,dc=company,dc=com");
directoryEntry.Properties["description"].Value = "new description";
directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```